# Какой знак препинания поставить?

Tags: пунктуация

Пять месяцев за тех, четыре месяца за других()везде все одинаково.
Знак препинания?

Comment: Может, Вы хотя бы потрудитесь обратиться к тем, у кого спрашиваете? Хотя бы "Какой знак препинания поставить?", я уж молчу о "спасибо" и "пожалуйста". Обращаетесь так, будто тут кто-то нанялся за Вас делать домашнюю работу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще-то, здесь тире, но делайте свои уроки сами, а потом заканчиваете школу и не можете собственное имя без ошибок написать. ПОЗОРИЩЕ!!

Comment: Мне 26 лет.Школу я закончил 11 лет назад.Нигде не учусь.Если бы у меня не было проблем с пунктуацией ,в отличие от орфографии,я бы не задавал вопросы на этом форуме.Просто мне стало интересно,захотелось подтянуть пунктуацию.И учебник мне помочь не смог,к сожалению.Потому что русский язык - это искусство и дуализм.Например:http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/24779/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD

Comment: и http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/24778/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C
Здесь допускается различное написание.И если это понятно филологу,то человеку со школьным образованием -это не всегда понятно.Отсюда и вопросы.Все вопросы,которые я задавал,были взяты мной из фраз различных людей.Где,как я считал,могут быть ошибки.Но не был в этом уверен.Простите,что не такой вежливый ,как вам хотелось бы.

Answer (score 1):

Но вежливость всё-таки не помешает:)